# How to put magento in maintenance

Tags: magento, webshop, magento-1.4

Is it possible to put a magento site under an maintenance flag so that visitors will get a message that the site is under construction?
I can't find this setting in the admin area.

Another solution will also be welcome.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I use this often. http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/maintenance-mode-in-magento/

The important part is:

> Open: index.php in root and above line 57 add (remembering to edit the ‘allowed’ array to contain the IP’s you want to be able to access the site);
>
> ```
> $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
> $allowed = array('1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2'); // these are the IP's that are allowed to view the site.
> ```
>
> then change the line
>
> ```
> if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && !in_array($ip, $allowed)) {
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I have put the maintenance.flag in the main directory. The only problem is that it shows the default Magento template with the error. Any idea how I can get this error message in my own theme design?

Comment: Look in the /errors/ directory. You can either edit the `default` skin that is there or create your own and enable it in a `local.xml` file. There is no way to use your existing theme for error pages which is a good thing, you might be working on that very theme which you don't want people to see.

Comment: try to use this http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/all4coding-offline-maintenance-page.html it is also support maintenance page with your design theme.

Comment: @JonSurrell you are correct.  I wasn't following SO guidelines.  In my defense this was one of my earliest answers.

Answer (score 30):

To enable maintenance mode in Magento, just create empty **maintenance.flag** file in the root of your Magento store.

Answer (score 11):

Just add a blank file called maintenance.flag to your root.. job done

A neater solution is to use [this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/store-maintenance.html).

it allow you to set the store up so that once logged into the back end you have access to the front + a few other neat features

Answer (score 6):

Thats what I add to the index in order to be able to continue working from different IPs:

```
//EGS to show a maintenance page but be able to work
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// these are the IP's that are  allowed to view the site:
$allowed = array('111.111.111.111', '222.222.222.222');

if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && !in_array($ip, $allowed)) { 
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento has **maintenance.flag** support built in. Check this out from

http://www.nicksays.co.uk/2010/07/enabling-magento-maintenance-mode/

Comment: SPELLING ERROR! `maintenance.flag`

Comment: Thanks @AndrewAtkinson, that's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

These are good modules to put your magento sites into maintenance mode anytime you want.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/store-maintenance.html

OR

If you want fun with working on the code then create `maintenance.flag` file which put your site into maintenance mode. And if you want to change the template of it then goto
`errors/default/503.phtml` file. Just change the design of it.

This is a simple solution.

Comment: SPELLING ERROR `maintenance.flag`

Answer (score 0):

The following would work with an apache installation (need to check with others).

You could create your own custom site under maintenance html page say `index.html` and place it in the root directory of your installation.

Open the `.htaccess` folder and rename the default page from `index.php` to `index.html`. Restart Apache. Once you are done rename the default page back to `index.php`.

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You may check this article, it has info about puting store to the maintenance for several IPs and have some working examples and needed files:

http://blog.magalter.com/page/how-to-temporarily-block-magento-store-access-put-website-to-maintenance-mode

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this tutorial](http://tutorialmagento.com/how-to-show-maintenance-mode-page-in-magento) to put my Magento store to maintenance mode, you may try as below:

1. Create a file name maintenance.flag in your magento root directory. Contents under this file doesn’t matter, you can keep it empty.
2. Change the maintenance file (located in magento root -> errors -> default directory) to show proper message when user visits your website.
   Hop this helps

Answer (score 0):

Check out this http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/all4coding-offline-maintenance-page.html it provide exactly what you are looking for. compatible with magento 1.4 - 1.8.

You can also display the maintenance page with your design theme.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial http://magentoexplorer.com/how-to-show-and-customize-magento-maintenance-mode-page to enable maintenance mode page in Magento, you need to create and upload maintenance.flag file to Magento root folder, however there are some more step for a good Maintenance mode like.

1. Add exception during maintenance (allow specific IP to visit your site during maintenance). In index.php, add these lines

   $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   $allowed = array('x.x.x.x','y.y.y.y');
2. Edit maintenance mode page
   Edit maintenance mode page in **/errors/default/503.phtml**
   Remove wrap in **/errors/default/page.phtml**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to put Magento in maintenance mode **only** in frontend,  leaving admin enabled for authentication you can try these steps:

1. Open index.php (from Magento root installation)
2. Search for the content below (around line 63):

   ```
   if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
   ```
3. Replace for:

   ```
   if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && !preg_match('/^\/(admin|index.php\/admin)/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
   ```
4. Create a blank file named **maintenance.flag** in your Magento root installation:

   ```
   $ touch maintenance.flag
   ```

This solution was inspired in the maintenance mode used in Opencart that uses the same behavior.

Answer (score -2):

Create an empty maintenance.flag file in the root of your Magento store.

Comment: What does this add to earlier answers?